# d3 radial tree bug with degenerate trees

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

I am building a program that displays trees using d3's radial tree (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550). I have no control over the incoming trees. I have a problem that if the incoming tree has only a single node (the root), then I get an error like this:

```
Error: Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="rotate(NaN)translate(0)"
```

I get the even more errors if the root has a single child, and so on (like a singly linked list of nodes). Here are the errors for two nodes:

```
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="MNaN,NaNCNaN,NaN NaN,NaN NaN,NaN"
Error: Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="rotate(NaN)translate(0)"
Error: Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="rotate(NaN)translate(180)"
Error: Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="rotate(NaN)translate(360)"
```

The problem seems to be that the x value of the node gets set to NaN. Does anyone know of a fix for this?

Comment: I figured out that the errors were coming from the division by a.depth in the separation function. I fixed that (returned 1 if a.depth was zero). That got rid of the errors, but now if I have a tree with two nodes (root and one child) the root gets drawn, and a line (pointing down) but the child node does not get drawn). Will keep working on this. But if someone has a more elegant solution, I would love to hear about it.

Comment: A shorter way to state this question is how to take a collapsible tree (like http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html or http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083 ) and turn it into a radial collapsible tree without getting an error or other problem when the user collapses the root node.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented your a.depth fix in the separation function, and it seems to be drawing properly:
http://jsfiddle.net/1Ljaajpf/1/

```
var tree = d3.layout.tree()
.size([360, diameter / 2 - 80])
.separation(function(a, b) { 
    // Added protection for degenerate case of one child
    if (a.depth == 0)
       return 1;

  return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 10) / a.depth; 
});
```

Maybe there is something else in your code which is causing drawing of the child to fail? For example, an issue with the translate/rotate/scale functions that could cause the child node to move out of visible area (or the child node is too small)